# Does Spring Data support OrientDB?

Tags: spring, spring-data, orientdb

We are working on a new project with OrientDB (Graph & document) so want to know if Spring-Data supports OrientDB and if the support is production-ready.

Answer (score 7):

The [official Spring Data project page](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/) provides a list of modules supported by Pivotal (the company that maintains Spring Data) as well as community-contributed modules.  OrientDB is not listed on this page so it is safe to assume that there is no Spring Data module for OrientDB yet that is endorsed by the Spring Data team.

However, Orient Technologies, the company that maintains OrientDB does provide a Spring Data module on [Github](https://github.com/orientechnologies/spring-data-orientdb).  Since the module has been developed by Orient Technologies, it would be worth looking at.

As for production-readiness, the Orient Technologies code is still in version `0.10.0-SNAPSHOT` and its Github repository does not have any releases yet, indicating that the code may be stable but has not been certified by the publisher for prime-time use.  One would have to try the code out to see if it meets one's requirements.

I have used some beta-versioned libraries in the past (including Spring Data MongoDB and Spring Data Neo4J) in production applications.  To decide whether a non production-ready library can be included in my applications, I look at the test coverage for the library to check whether my use cases are covered and to what extent.  In some cases I have added my own unit tests to ensure that the libraries would function as expected for my use cases.  Another indicator of overall quality is the number of tests and the test coverage so one can look at those as well.

In the end, even software certified to be production-ready can have bugs (and I have reported several bugs in Spring Data modules myself) so having a production versioned library is only a small assurance that it can be used in live applications.  The real test will come from one's own use cases and business requirements.

Comment: Thanks Manish. it really help me to understand how to take up open source. new to work with open source. They do not have template for graph so planning to write one. Thanks again